# How to upgrade the version of npm?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I want to upgrade the version of npm while I used comments for installing the latest version,yet all showing an error
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn07G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
npm i -g npm
```

With npm upgrades npm :D